Substrate node handshake
I'm trying to do substrate node handshake. As far as I understand we first do Noise XX handshake with our initial request and then we proceed to upgrade the connection.
With the following code the substrate-node-template is accepting my connection but it's returning empty response:
    // snow crate 0.9.6
    let builder: Builder<'_> = Builder::new("Noise_XX_25519_ChaChaPoly_BLAKE2s".parse().unwrap());
    let keypair = builder.generate_keypair().unwrap();
    let static_private_key = keypair.private.clone();
    let static_public_key = keypair.public.clone();

    // Initialize Noise with the local private key
    let mut noise = builder
        .local_private_key(&static_private_key)
        .build_initiator()
        .unwrap();

    // Perform the initial handshake step (Message 1)
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; 65535];
    let len = noise.write_message(&[], &mut buf).unwrap();
    println!("Sending 1st msg");
    stream.write_all(&buf[..len]).await?;
    stream.flush().await?;

I expect that the node will return me his authentication data as described here:
https://spec.polkadot.network/chap-networking
https://noiseexplorer.com/patterns/XX/
I assume that I'm missing something but can't figure out what. I'm using simple tcp streams as I don't care what will happen after the handshake is done or for any post traffic.

Looking offhand at the code:

you are using Noise_XX_25519_ChaChaPoly_BLAKE2s, while substrate is using Noise_XX_25519_ChaChaPoly_SHA256
We are using an initial message of let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 256]; instead of 65535. That shouldn't matter tho.
You'd need to read from the socket to receive the handshake message

We have a few examples in our litep2p crate:

Step 1. Submit the initial message. This looks correct from the code you provide
Step 2. Read the handshake

I believe step 2 is missing here, let me know if this helped, thanks!
